# How to change style of a class without JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Suppose to have about 2000 elements in a page like

```
<div class="good">fruit</div>
<div class="bad">stone</div>
<div class="bad">sand</div>
<div class="good">water</div>
<div class="good">carrot</div>
```

and style is

```
.good { color: green }
.bad  { color: red }
```

I want to change css "color" value of classes "good" and "bad" without iterate getElementsByClassName. E.g. something like (invented)

```
document.class["good"].style.color="yellow"
```

I didn't find any way to change class definition in order to let all tags marked with that class change style: do it exists? Is it possible?

MANDATORY: I {don't want, can't} use jQuery.

**EDIT:** I need to do it via Javascript, or find a way to change a attribute of whole class so that whole page is affected by change **at the same time** (I repeat, without iteration over document.getElementsByClassName("good")). I mean, I don't want use getElementsByClassName. I want that style element "color" is changed for class "good" so that "good" class has color "yellow" instead than "green". I don't want to change style of elements of document with that class, I want to change style of class. Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: Regarding your edit: `"I don't want to change style of elements of document with that class, I want to change style of class."`: possible, but this leads to unpredictable software/html design. It occures to me that you want to implement some theming / theme switching. If it's the case I'd recommend to create another stylesheet where all the variable styling goes. When changing the style you duplicate that stylesheet, change the values and just change the stylesheet in the DOM, not single styles.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case. I'm working with GreaseMonkey for a script that accesses a really complex page (sic!) with about 5000 elements having the same structure as in my example. I can't use jQuery for a reason too long to explain, and changing elements attributes via getElementsByClassName is *really* slow, but trick suggested by Nenad was perfect: immediate action, no need to wait 3-4 seconds for the script to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByClassName()` but then you must to loop  HTMLCollection [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/698/)

```js
var good = document.getElementsByClassName('good');
for (var i = 0; i < good.length; i++) {
  good[i].style.color = 'yellow';
}
```

Update: You can change css `class` with [`Document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) and this is how. Note: You need to find correct number of your css file, in this demo its `[0]`

```js
var changeStyle = function(selector, prop, value) {
  var style = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules || document.styleSheets[0].rules;
  for (var i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
    if (style[i].selectorText == selector) {
      style[i].style[prop] = value;
    }
  }
}

changeStyle('.good', 'color', 'purple');
changeStyle('.bad', 'color', 'yellow');
```

```css
.good { color: green }
.bad  { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="good">fruit</div>
<div class="bad">stone</div>
<div class="bad">sand</div>
<div class="good">water</div>
<div class="good">carrot</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: "I want to change css "color" value of classes "good" and "bad" without iterate getElementsByClassName."

Comment: I know that... but definitively, I'm unable to be understood. I want to change class definition, not change attributes of tags with that class.

Comment: @Sampisa i updated my answer i think that is what you are looking for

Comment: Great!!! Thank you!
I found after some time the same answer. If I define my stylesheet e.g. with an id, and I put just my 2 "bad" and "good "styles, it is easy to retrieve it, then directly set color property. [+1] for you :)

Comment: I was trying to change a root: --my-var-value and i wasn't having any luck with this. Found this similar question that worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Using **CSS Selectors** is another vital way .

visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("god");
for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].className += " bad";
}
```