# How to change CSS :root color variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, I'm creating a system for my webpage that allows users to change the theme. How I want to accomplish this is by having all the colors as variables, and the colors are set in the :root part of the CSS.

What I want to do is change those colors via JavaScript. I looked up how to do it, but nothing that I attempted actually worked properly. Here's my current code:

CSS:

```
:root {
  --main-color: #317EEB;
  --hover-color: #2764BA;
  --body-color: #E0E0E0;
  --box-color: white;
}
```

JS:

(Code to set the theme, it's ran on the click of a button) - I didn't bother adding the :root change to the other 2 themes since it doesn't work on the Dark theme

```
function setTheme(theme) {
  if (theme == 'Dark') {
    localStorage.setItem('panelTheme', theme);
    $('#current-theme').text(theme);
    $(':root').css('--main-color', '#000000');
  }
  if (theme == 'Blue') {
    localStorage.setItem('panelTheme',  'Blue');
    $('#current-theme').text('Blue');
    alert("Blue");
  }
  if (theme == 'Green') {
    localStorage.setItem('panelTheme', 'Green');
    $('#current-theme').text('Green');
    alert("Green");
  }
}
```

(Code that is ran when the html  is loaded)

```
function loadTheme() {
  //Add this to body onload, gets the current theme. If panelTheme is empty, defaults to blue.
  if (localStorage.getItem('panelTheme') == '') {
    setTheme('Blue');
  } else {
    setTheme(localStorage.getItem('panelTheme'));
    $('#current-theme').text(localStorage.getItem('panelTheme'));
  }
}
```

It shows the alert, but does not actually change anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your js in run when the document is ready? How do you determine that it 'does not change anything'? Change your example to something closer to a [MCVE]

Comment: Updated the OP with more code, sorry.

Comment: It's still not obvious what you expect to change. for instance, on your console you can type, say, `$(':root').css("background-color", "#000000")` and see things change. So if something visual change is not taking place, the problem is likely not your code (unless it's running before document ready)

Comment: I want to change the color of the variables with JS. For instance, in my example I'm attempting to change --main-color from  #317EEB to #000000.

Comment: Open up the console. Run the statement that sets the color. Run a statement that queries the color. See if you get what you set.

Comment: I queried "--main-color" and got "#\33 17EEB" returned. When I ran the code to change the color, it prints out some HTML code then doesn't change anything. When I query the color after I attempt to change it, it returns the same thing it originally did.

Comment: I don't really know exactly what jquery does with css variables, which are a fairly new addition. See this example for manipulating them without jq. If your browser is new enough where you are asking for css var support, you probably don't need jq anyway. https://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/adQjoY

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Thank you @pvg for providing the link. I had to stare at it for a little to understand what was going on, but I finally figured it out.

The magical line I was looking for was this:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--your-variable', '#YOURCOLOR');
```

That did exactly what I wanted it to do, thank you very much!

Comment: ironically it looks like getPropertyValue is not woking with :root css variables, but setting does

Comment: The way to get the value is: 
`getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--my-var");`

Comment: i like using `document.querySelector(":root")` instead of `document.documentElement`, as i am sure this is the same element as `:root { ... }` in css

Comment: `document.querySelector(':root') === document.documentElement` returns `true` - however, TypeScript complains about the former one; I doubt there's a good reason for it complaining though :/

Comment: To all previous commenters: this solution does what it sais, sets a var in `document.documentElement` aka `html`, and it works despite the fact that `html` has lower specificity just because javascript sets the style **inline**! See `Dev Tools` and [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root)

Comment: Can we give `transition speed` via javascript?

Comment: @MaxWaterman `document.querySelector(':root')` returns type `Element` vs `documentElement` which guarantees `HTMLElement`. You could use type assertion `(document.querySelector(':root') as HTMLElement).style` but thats pretty gross...

Comment: @Steve ok, but why does document.querySelector(':root') === document.documentElement return true? & both are 'instanceof HTMLElement'....IMO, typescript is wrong.

Comment: @MaxWaterman Well with `documentElement`, you are going straight to the element which we know for certain is the `HTMLElement`. `querySelector` returns the first Element it finds matching your query. Element is the base class - many classes such as `SVGElement` and `HTMLElement` inherit from it. Because we are passing it a string (crossing the line of how smart TS can be), it can't be sure that you will get an `HTMLElement` although for this single case... we know it will be `HTMLElement`. You could use something that guarantees an `HTMLElement`: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`.

Comment: @Steve yes, I get that now...with querySelector() there's no way to know before runtime if it is an HTMLElement or not.

Answer (score 27):

I think this is cleaner and easier to remember.
to set/get css variables to/from `:root`

```
const root = document.querySelector(':root');

// set css variable
root.style.setProperty('--my-color', 'blue');

// to get css variable from :root
const color = getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--my-color'); // blue
```

**Example: setting multiple variables all at once**

```
const setVariables = vars => Object.entries(vars).forEach(v => root.style.setProperty(v[0], v[1]));
const myVariables = {
  '--color-primary-50': '#eff6ff',
  '--color-primary-100': '#dbeafe',
  '--color-primary-200': '#bfdbfe',
  '--color-primary-300': '#93c5fd',
  '--color-primary-400': '#60a5fa',
  '--color-primary-500': '#3b82f6',
  '--color-primary-600': '#2563eb',
  '--color-primary-700': '#1d4ed8',
  '--color-primary-800': '#1e40af',
  '--color-primary-900': '#1e3a8a',
};
setVariables(myVariables);
```

Comment: That is not "at once" - that is just codding an iterator on the properties of an object!

Comment: @horiatu,  it is how underlying `CSSStyleDeclaration` interface works - you set properties one by one. It is actually correct idiomatic way to add properties

Answer (score 25):

For those who want to modify the actual style sheet the following works:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.insertRule(":root{--blue:#4444FF}");
```

More info at here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Comment: i just discovered that "setProperty" does something similar, maybe.  so i am wondering if this would work too?   
`document.body.style.setProperty('--blue', '#4444ff');` what do you think?

Comment: @edwardsmarkf that way is changing the DOM whereas the code above is changing the style sheet itself.  Changing the stylesheet allows for themes to change on the fly without reloading.  All elements using the --blue variable immediately change when the color value is changed.  With the DOM you have to change each element you want to update.

Comment: thanks - i "discovered" this after i made the comment, otherwise i probably should have removed it.
i have learned as well that using the insertRule might conflict with a previous rule, and perhaps the original rule should be removed? It's strange that we cannot easily add new rule to existing rule without some jScript acrobatics like appending new rule after the initial semicolon.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf Daedalus's solution also updates the theme without reloading, so this seems superior since you can overwrite existing properties - which avoids those acrobatics.

Answer (score 8):

To use the values of custom properties in JavaScript, it is just like standard properties.

```
// get variable from inline style
element.style.getPropertyValue("--my-variable");

// get variable from wherever
getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--my-variable");

// set variable on inline style
element.style.setProperty("--my-variable", 4);
```

Comment: The first example doesn't work for `:root` css properties - it only works for values that have been set directly with `setProperty`. Need to use `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(......)`

Answer (score 5):

I came here looking how to toggle the `:root` [color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme) with JavaScript, which sets the browser to dark mode (including the scroll bars) like this:

```css
:root {
    color-scheme: dark;
}
```

using the @Daedalus answer above, this is how I implemented my dark mode detection from user preference:

```js
    const userPrefersDarkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
    const preferredTheme = userPrefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light';
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("color-scheme", preferredTheme);
```

or with saved toggle:

```js
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (savedTheme == 'dark') {
        thisTheme = 'light'
    }
    else {
        thisTheme = 'dark'; // the default when never saved is dark
    }
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("color-scheme", thisTheme);
    localStorage.setItem('theme', thisTheme);
```

see also the optional [meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name) in the header:

```html
<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">
```

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

A solution to the problem could be the below code:

```
const headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const styleTag = document.createElement("style");

styleTag.innerHTML = `
:root {
    --main-color: #317EEB;
    --hover-color: #2764BA;
    --body-color: #E0E0E0;
    --box-color: white;
}
`;
headTag.appendChild(styleTag);
```

**Explanation:**

Although @Daedalus answer with `document.documentElement` does the job pretty well, a slightly better approach is to add the styling into a `<style>` HTML tag (solution proposed).

If you add `document.documentElement.style` then all the CSS variables are added into the `html` tag and they are not hidden:

[image: CSS style inline to html]

On the other hand, with the proposed code:

```
const headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const styleTag = document.createElement("style");

styleTag.innerHTML = `
:root {
    --main-color: #317EEB;
    --hover-color: #2764BA;
    --body-color: #E0E0E0;
    --box-color: white;
}
`;
headTag.appendChild(styleTag);
```

the HTML tag will be cleaner and if you inspect the HTML tag you can also see the `:root` styling as well.

[image: HTML tag without styles]

Comment: Good point on how it looks upon inspection.

Answer (score 2):

old jquery magic still working too

```
$('#yourStyleTagId').html(':root {' +
    '--your-var: #COLOR;' +
'}');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Read only**, retrieve all CSS `--root` rules in an array, without using `.getComputedStyle()`.

This may allow to retrieve values before full DOM content load, to create modules that use global root theme variables, but not via CSS. (canvas context...)

```js
/* Retrieve all --root CSS variables
*  rules into an array
*  Without using getComputedStyle (read string only)
*  On this example only the first style-sheet
*  of the document is parsed
*/
console.log(

  [...document.styleSheets[0].rules]
   .map(a => a.cssText.split(" ")[0] === ":root" ?
    a.cssText.split("{")[1].split("}")[0].split("--") : null)
   .filter(a => a !== null)[0]
   .map(a => "--"+a)
   .slice(1)

)
```

```css
:root {
    --gold: hsl(48,100%,50%);
    --gold-lighter: hsl(48,22%,30%);
    --gold-darker: hsl(45,100%,47%);
    --silver: hsl(210,6%,72%);
    --silver-lighter: hsl(0,0%,26%);
    --silver-darker: hsl(210,3%,61%);
    --bronze: hsl(28,38%,67%);
    --bronze-lighter: hsl(28,13%,27%);
    --bronze-darker: hsl(28,31%,52%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer of DEV Tiago França, which worked on my case. here is why it works like a charm:

```
/* Root original style */
:root {
    --hl-color-green: green;
}
/* Using * overrides the variable for all html tags where it is actually used */
* {
    --hl-color-green: #0cc120;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target the stylesheet you can do this:

```
    const styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0]

    const ruleIndex = [...styleSheet.cssRules].findIndex(rule => rule.cssText.includes('--sidebar:'))
    const ruleText = styleSheet.cssRules[ruleIndex].cssText
    let newRule: string

    if (isOpen()) newRule = ruleText.replace('--sidebar: var(--sidebar-open)', '--sidebar: var(--sidebar-closed)')
    else newRule = ruleText.replace('--sidebar: var(--sidebar-closed)', '--sidebar: var(--sidebar-open)')

    styleSheet.deleteRule(ruleIndex)
    styleSheet.insertRule(newRule, ruleIndex)
```

Just be sure that the string to replace is exactly the same as in your stylesheet, including spaces;

CSS:

```
:root {
    --sidebar: var(--sidebar-open);
    --sidebar-open: 15rem;
    --sidebar-closed: 2rem;
}
```

Text to teplace:

Works:

`--sidebar: var(--sidebar-open)`

Doesn't works (One space is missing):

`--sidebar:var(--sidebar-open)`

The answer from @Michael works, but it adds a new rule every time you switch the style.

Answer (score 0):

```
private switchDarkMode = (value: boolean) => {
    let darkStyles = document.getElementById("darkStyles");
    if (!darkStyles) {
        darkStyles = domConstruct.create(
            "style",
            {
                id: "darkStyles",
            },
            document.head
        );
    }
    darkStyles.innerHTML = `
:root {
    --white: ${!value ? "white" : "black"};
};
`;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
/*My style*/
:root {
    --hl-color-green: green;
}

/*My update*/
* {
 --hl-color-green: #0cc120;
}
```