# How to change CSS root variable in React?

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs

Is it possible to change CSS `:root` variable in ReactJS ? looking for solution to change `--base`color code based on what user selected from `.change-me` input color

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgXBEK

**CSS**

```
:root {
  --base: $primary;
}
```

**React**

```
changeTheme(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptates ut eaque, voluptatum veniam nostrum sequi numquam sint, excepturi amet unde quis, ipsum ducimus reprehenderit eligendi pariatur animi esse sed.</p>
                    <input 
                      className="" 
                      type="color" 
                      onChange={this.changeTheme.bind(this)}
                      />
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

Comment: i guess you have to exclude it from scss

Comment: @Muhaimin Looking for solution something like `document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.id}`, this.value + suffix);`

Comment: perhaps you can use `ref` on componentDidMount

Comment: @Muhaimin I found something. What you think about the answer given below ?

Comment: fine by me. how's the result

Comment: @Muhaimin woks fine but not sure about coding style

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally found solution

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {color: '#3C454B'};
}
changeTheme(e){
    this.setState({color: event.target.value});
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--base',this.state.color);
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptates ut eaque, voluptatum veniam nostrum sequi numquam sint, excepturi amet unde quis, ipsum ducimus reprehenderit eligendi pariatur animi esse sed.</p>
                    <input 
                      className="" 
                      type="color" 
                      defaultValue={this.state.color}
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleColor(e)}
                      />
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the color in App.css, and then call it across the app?This way, I won't have to do a document.setProperty for every element (that is the hope, anyway)

Comment: just a note: setState might not finish setting your state before you call the next line. so either use event.target.value in the `document.documentElement...` line or setState's second parameter is a callback that is called when the state is set.

Comment: @marcellsimon good point

Answer (score 8):

I found out that you can change the root variable from any element. By wrapping the variable in double quotes `"--base"` and using it as the key in your style object.

```
<input 
    className="" 
    type="color" 
    onChange={this.changeTheme.bind(this)}
    style={{"--base":this.state.color}}
/>
```

Comment: This one saved me! it's really useful for setting up styles for individual elements

Comment: nice solution, but will not work for typescript

Comment: this one is best and cleaner solution, thanks

Comment: How can we make this work for TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802204
`document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--your-variable', '#YOURCOLOR');`