# Setting a value in CSS from React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Having trouble parameterizing css such that animationSpeed is taken from props.

I would want to replace the .2s below with animationSpeed

transitions.css

```
.Anim-appear {
  animation: .2s linear pageFadeIn, .2s linear pageSlideInLeft;
}
...
```

component.jsx

```
import '../css/transitions.css';

const PageAnimator = props => {
     const animationSpeed = props.animationSpeed + 's' // How to use this to set animationSpeed in CSS?
 }
```

I am having a lot of trouble doing this and was wondering how I could get this done.

Note: this value doesn't change. After we initialize the app it is a constant value. But we have several versions of the App that all have different configurations and animation speeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--animation-speed', sec);
```

That's how I accomplished it. It seems to work. : )

Thanks to:

[How to change CSS root variable in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226712/how-to-change-css-root-variable-in-react)