# How to change root element variable dynamically when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

```
:root {
  --main-color: #0d1117;
  --back-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
  --text-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

The above is my root element in my React APP.

There is a button somewhere. When that button is clicked, I want to be able to change the variables. For example, `--back-color` should be green.

When that variable is change, will my entire APP re-render with the new color?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226712/how-to-change-css-root-variable-in-react answer above

Comment: *"When that variable is change, will my entire APP re-render with the new color?"* - no, React will only re-render when state changes. CSS isn't react state.