# Setting a computed style (Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed)

Tags: javascript, css

For background I am trying to create a dark mode on my site. I want a user to be able to click a button that flips the sites colors. 
So far I have pieced together this javascript snippet

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body);

function darkMode() {
    if (style.getPropertyValue('--text-white') === "rgb(254, 254, 254)") {
        style.setProperty('--text-white', "rgb(43, 42, 42)");
        style.setProperty('--text-black', "rgb(254, 254, 254)");
    } else {
        style.setProperty('--text-white', "rgb(254, 254, 254)");
        style.setProperty('--text-black', "rgb(43, 42, 42)");
    }
}
```

My aim was to update the variables in a css file under :root

```
:root {
  --text-white: rgb(254, 254, 254);
  --text-black: rgb(43, 42, 42);
}
```

`style.getPropertyValue` is able to return the right values but when I try to run the rest of the code I get

> (index):191 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the '--text-white' property is read-only.

Any tips on how to move forward on this?

Comment: Also [How to change CSS :root color variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: You got it! Thanks for the help Mohammad!