# Why first CSS variable resets when I change second? Custom color theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables, setattribute

The purpose is to make a custom site color theme. The problem is when I changing the second CSS variable first resets to its default value.

[image]

[image]

```js
var mainColor = document.getElementById("main-color");
var secondColor = document.getElementById("second-color");

function color(cssVariable, inputValue) {
  return cssVariable + ":" + inputValue
}

mainColor.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", color("--main-color", this.value))
})

secondColor.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", color("--second-color", this.value))
})
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: black;
  --second-color: whitesmoke;
  --main-font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-size: var(--main-font-size);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-color-container">
  <input type="color" id="main-color">
  <input type="color" id="second-color">
</div>
```

Is there any way to save changed CSS variables? And how would you implement code for this, what's the easiest solution? *I'm beginner in JS*

Runnable code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLDQWOUT9HUA

Comment: your code seems to work fine

Comment: @TemaniAfif gif added

Comment: we don't need gif, we need a runnable code that highlight the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif check picture too, I think there is very helpful info. If no clue I'll add runnable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the style attribute so each time you override all the previous inline style.

You need to do it differently using `setProperty`

```js
var mainColor = document.getElementById("main-color");
var secondColor = document.getElementById("second-color");

function color(cssVariable, inputValue) {
  return cssVariable + ":" + inputValue
}

mainColor.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--main-color", this.value);
})

secondColor.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--second-color", this.value)
})
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: black;
  --second-color: whitesmoke;
  --main-font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-size: var(--main-font-size);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-color-container">
  <input type="color" id="main-color">
  <input type="color" id="second-color">
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line
`document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", color("--main-color", this.value));`

to

`document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--main-color", this.value);`

Refer:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802204/979621)

Demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f8ojnwL/)