# Link which will change text color

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if it's possible to add additional data to the link based on which the page will be opened with a certain change in CSS?

Or is there a better way how it can be done?

e.g. when I click on one of the three links, this parameter changes in CSS.

link 1 changes: :root {
--primary-color: red;

link 2 changes: :root {
--primary-color: blue;

link 3 changes: :root {
--primary-color: green;

Or maybe it's complete nonsense what I'm trying to accomplish.
I won't be using it for color, but for another parameter, but if you can show me how it can be done with a color I guess, I'll manage to do it with another parameter.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html - red">Red</a>
    <a href="index.html - blue">Blue</a>    
    <a href="index.html - green">Green</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you are looking at is query params in url.. You need to pass index.html?color=red / index.html?color=blue, index.html?color=green and your server need to capture what you pass in color field.

Comment: It is possible but not that easy. You could change the root variables values with javascript. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript . This is if you use the same index.html. So you don't actually ' navigate ' but only change the variables values. So you would need a ' preventDefault ' on your click event on the links

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change CSS :root color variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. And if I need to change the     "display: block;" into     "display: none;" for one element, is it possible?

Comment: Hi Edvard I think This will help you ! https://www.techiedelight.com/change-elements-display-to-none-or-block-javascript/

Comment: I have tried this method, but it does everything on the same page and I would like to have a similar effect when you open a new page. E.g. I open a new page where one element is already hidden and another element is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  Use search params together with javascript. see example below and ' comment '

```js
const myUrl = "?color=red" // here use window.location.search
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(myUrl);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
const myColor = params.color

 document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--my-color", myColor);
```

```css
:root {
  --my-color: yellow
  }
  
  h1 {
  color: var(--my-color)
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="change-color"  href="index.html/?color=red">Red</a>
    <a class="change-color"  href="index.html/?color=blue">Blue</a>    
    <a class="change-color"  href="index.html/?color=green">Green</a>
    <h1>Change me</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one also does it on the same page. I would like it to work across multiple pages. When I open a red link page two opens where "Change me" is written in red. When I open blue link page two opens where "Change me" is written in blue.