# How can I change :root properties without modifying the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I have this in my file.css

```
:root {
  --the-color: #fff;
}
```

with JavaScript I'm changing the `--the-color` value like this

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--the-color', "#000");
```

This sets a new property which overrides the existing one
but I don't want my DOM elements to appear like this when js used `<html style="--the-color: #000;">`

Edit:
let me ask my question differently
how do i change a `div` css color property with javascript but without my DOM element appear like this `<div style="--the-color: #000;">`

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript

Comment: The second answer though, because he doesn't want to change the DOM element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change CSS :root color variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: No it does not help. i dont want to change my DOM elements or at least another solution to setProperty like updateProperty :D

Comment: I edited my post