# Is there a way the get the number of child elements and store it as a variable in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the number of elements in a div with css and set a variable to the returned value. I've looked at using js, but you can't edit css variables.

Here's how I reckon it might look:

```html
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
        
    <div class="navbar">

        <a href="index.html"> Home </a>
        <a href="index.html"> About </a>
        <a href="index.html"> Listings </a>
        <a href="index.html"> Info </a>
        <a href="index.html"> Profile </a>

    </div>

</body>
```

```scss
:root {

    --total-navbar-items: document(.navbar a:count)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

*I've looked at using js, but you can't edit css variables* : Apparently yes, [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802204/17684809)

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'orange');  
})
```

```css
:root{
  --color: green;
}
div{
  background-color:var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div>Hi</div>
<button id="btn">change color</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change a number variable? Because turning the number into a string then passing it as the argument doesn't work.

Comment: @Kai If you don't want a string, just use this without quotes like `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--total-navbar-items', 5)`

Comment: @Kai tell me if you succeeded. If not, you may have to edit your post to add additionnal informations of your context or else