# Accessing mixin elements from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sass, scss-mixins

I have @mixin in .scss file:

```scss
@mixin def
{
    background-color: var(--bs-gray-dark);
    color: white;
}
```

and I want to access elements in that mixin from JavaScript so I don't have manually change values of everything that use this mixin.
Entire SCSS file:

```scss
@mixin def
{
    background-color: var(--bs-gray-dark);
    color: white;
}

body
{
    @include def;
}

.row
{
    @include def;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to update the value of `--bs-gray-dark` css var via a JS function of some sort?

Comment: Yes, background-color and color

Comment: If I were you I would set your mixin to point to two custom css props (i.e. css variables) and then update them as is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need.
SCSS file just for someone other:
```
:root
{
    --bg-color: var(--bs-gray-dark);
    --fg-color: white;
}

@mixin def
{
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--fg-color);
}

body
{
    @include def
}

.row
{
    @include def;
}
```

Comment: You can also check this link for readable code: https://github.com/ringwormGO-organization/Website/tree/main/ringwormGO-new