# How to change background color of a page while avoiding iframes/images/videos using js/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am new to CSS/JS and I am creating an accessibility chrome extension and I need to change the background color of the page. The problem I encounter is when changing the color of pages that have videos like twitch and youtube.

```
function changeBKColorPredefined(background, color) {    
var tags = document.querySelectorAll("*");

for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].style.backgroundColor = background;
    tags[i].style.color = color;
}
}
```

This code clearly changes *everything* there is on the page, but I don't know how to avoid changing the background color of certain tags without having to specifying them which would of course become a really hard to maintain code.

Example output of the code showed before:

[image]

I have also tried to only change the body color by using `document.body.style.backgroundColor` but it does not change the color of the whole page.

Thank you for any help.

Edit: an example of what I mean can be found in this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/a%20-fontsize-changer/ckihgechpahhpompcinglebkgcdgpkil

Comment: You want to avoid certain tags without specifying them? Seems like an impossible task. If not, I'd suggest something like `document.querySelectorAll("*:not(iframe,img,video)");`

Comment: @Reyno the problem is that pages like youtube don't really use those tags, they use others like <ytd-rich-grid-media> and tons of others and I think it wouldn't make sense to just exclude those and call it a day. And it also generates another problem that is that I can't go around every page to select the specific tags they use. Still, thank you. Didn't know about the :not in querySelector

Answer (score -1):

Use [css custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) also known as CSS Variables. This way you can set in your CSS property value as background, and then change only said value.

Simple example would be:

```css
:root {
/**
 * This will be your default value. In this example - black.
 */
  --changing-background: #000;
}

/**
 * In places where you want to change backround set it as background color
 */
.classes-with-changing-background {
  background-color: var(--changing-background);
}
```

Then in JS you do:

```js
// This is your JS. In my example we change property value to white
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--changing-background', '#fff');
```

I took JS from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802204/2318162)

Comment: How are they supposed to modify the stylesheets of every webpage their extension modifies to support this?

Comment: It is possible to inject CSS `:root {--changing-background: #default-color} *:not(iframe, video, img, whatewer-to-exclude) {background-color: var(--changning-color)}`

Comment: Read the problem statement from the question again — *I don't know how to avoid changing the background color of certain tags without having to specifying them which would of course become a really hard to maintain code* — You don't seem to have addressed that.