Get CSS color variables from JSON file
How can I use JS to set CSS variables (:root) from a JSON file?
The format of my data is as follows:
css_json: 
{ 
--design-white: “#f1f2f9” 
--main-flamingo: “#8e24aa” 
}

My variables will be used as an example like this:
color: var(--main-flamingo). Which option might be more flexible in my situation?

You can set css variables using setProperty:
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--main-flamingo", "#fc8eac");

To get the value use getPropertyValue:
document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue("--main-flamingo");

The JSON  part can be done using JSON.parse:
const rawJson = `{
  "--design-white": "#f1f2f9",
  "--main-flamingo": "#8e24aa"
}`;

const parsed = JSON.parse(rawJson);

document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
  "--main-flamingo",
  parsed["--main-flamingo"],
);


you missing a few steps. First of all, you need to fetch the JSON from the server. Then you need to parse it to a normal object and then you need to loop through the object.  ALso, the OP want to set set CSS variables properly to the stylesheet not to the HTMl document which can be done with the 3rd answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801882/how-to-change-css-root-color-variables-in-javascript

and for looping through the object you might want to read through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members

@tacoshy you are right that one could use fetch to load the JSON, another option would be to use import.
Since the question did not actually mention how the JSON is to be procured, or whether it already has been, I refrained from giving a subpar answer.
Furthermore the focus of the question is very clearly on the CSS variables, not JSON.

I am also not sure where you are getting this part from "OP want to set set CSS variables properly to the stylesheet not to the HTMl document", since the question simply asks to set a CSS variable ("How can I use JS to set CSS variables (:root) from a JSON file?").
Since the question did not specify, I simply suggested the method I knew :)

All right, this is the realization I was looking for. There is just one small detail. The addition of all variables is written to the style html tag, which is not critical, but I would like to know if there is any way to hide the styles from there? That's probably what :root was doing, and now we add directly to the styles of the main tag
